# Deleting rows in training dataset for Random Forest

Tags: r, random-forest

I want to run my random forest with a modified version of my training dataset. My training data contains different columns including one called `attribute` with values from 0-6. My idea was to delete just the `0` and keep the rest using this bit of code:

```
training_data4 <- training_data3[!training_data3$attribute == "0", ]
```

However, when I run my random forest with my training data I am receiving this error message:

```
rf200 <- randomForest(attribute ~ ., data=training_data4, importance=T, 
                      proximity=F, ntree=200 )
```

> Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : Can't have empty classes in
>   y

I already know there must be something wrong with my `training_data4`, as I tried it already with my original training set and this did not have this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Is `attribute` a `factor` (i.e., `class(training_data3$attribute)` returns `factor`)?

If so, R retains `0` as a level, and you will have to explicitly use `droplevels` to make sure `0` is no longer a level of that `factor`:

```
training_data4 <- training_data3[!training_data3$attribute == "0", ]
training_data4$attribute <- droplevels(training_data4$attribute)
```

---

Example:

```
test <- factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), levels=c("0", "1", "2", "3"))
test
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
Levels: 0 1 2 3

test <- droplevels(test)
test
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
Levels: 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it worked well with the droplevel.